# VSTO AddIn for Word hanging for more than 20sec at startup, but only for some clients

Tags: ms-word, vsto, startup, office-addins

I produced a VSTO Addin for word that is distributed as ClickOnce installer. Some clients have very slow startup times of word if the addin is activated (around 20secs), while most users don't seem to suffer from that problem (startup <1 sec). I can't reproduce the problem on my development machine. Deactivating the addin reduces the startup time to normal for them and deactivating all other addins does not bring any improvement. The client machines in question are standalone machines, no business network.

The addin itself is pretty light weight, it mainly starts a taskpane with a standard webbrowser element. The only depedencies are the .NET framework 4.7.2 and VS 2010 tools for office runtime. According to the users word displays the startup step "processing" during the waiting time.

Any ideas on how I can further investigate the problem with limited access to the client machine? Any guesses about the source of the problem?

Comment: Check the Startup Sub of your add-in for anything that might cause an excessive delay. Are you doing anything special with Word's ribbon?

Comment: The ribbon has literally nothing, but a button and a method connected to it, to open/close the taskpane. The startup sub of the addin loads the taskpane and reads one property from the settings file.I will deactivate the automatic loading of the taskpane at startup and ask the customer to test again, just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: To test Rich Michaels suggestion, I deactivated the loading of the taskpane in the startup sub. Indeed the client then reported a normal starting time for word, but that just shifted the waiting time to the moment the taskpane loading was activated manually. The client also reported that the waiting time would not occur after word had been running for a while, before loading the taskpane.

Comment: That leads me to guess that the .NET framework might be loading extremely slowly on the client machine. If the taskpane is loaded later, the frame has had time to load in the background.